# Inequality from a property of convexity

Tags: functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a convex function.

How can I prove that for each $x$, there is $c$ such that $f(x)+c(y-x)\leq f(y)$ for all $y$?

One of the difficulties to solve is $f$ does not need to be differentiable. It makes me feel hard. So I must show this inequality by only using the definition of a convex function:
$$f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\leq\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$$
holds for any $\lambda\in[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Take $x$ real and $t\neq 0$. Define
$$v(t)=\frac{f(x)-f(x+t)}{t}$$

Show that $v$ is increasing. Define
$$c^-=\lim_{t\to0^-} v(t)$$
and
$$c^+=\lim_{t\to0^+}v(t)$$

Now, take $c\in[c^-,c^+]$.